# Trying to use a returned value without the other parts of a function

Tags: python, function, variables, return-value

I have a very simply function that returns a value.

```
def GetNumber():
    Number = 45
    print("Getting Number")
    print("Found Number = " + str(Number))
    return Number

def UseNumber(current):
    print("The current number is: " + str(current))

UseNumber(GetNumber())
```

However, my output is the following:

> Getting Number
>
> Found Number = 45
>
> The current number is: 45

I use the print outs from the `def GetNumber` in another part of my application, so I need to keep them there, but I would like to extract the value from GetNumber without having to rerun the whole GetNumber function each time.

How can I use a returned value without having it actually run the whole function and print out?

Ideally, I would like my output to simply be:

> The current number is: 45

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Rewrite the function (to perform intended behavior, possibly using a parameter as a switch) and/or call a different function.

Comment: I don't know why this is getting down voted into oblivion. I'm new to Python and trying to learn. This is the best way I can learn. Excuse me for not being a blatant professional such as the rest of you.

Comment: You have explicitly written lines of code to print stuff to the console but then ask how do you make stuff stop printing to the console?

Comment: The phrase "This is the best way I can learn" is dubious at best. An important rule of programming is: the code does what it was told. Anyway, there are *many* beginning resources available that will "walk through" building programs by showing the basic building blocks and logic; programming is simply repeatedly applying these building blocks in slightly different ways. Like making a cake.

Comment: @level42 See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info and "Free Python programming Books".

Comment: @csm_dev, I need the print for another purpose of my application. I'm trying to understand how to get the best of both worlds here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be done this way. One way to handle this is to refactor the code, to break out the parts that are used in different parts in separate functions and then just call the parts needed, where needed. In this toy example this could be achieved as:

```
def get_number():
    number = 45
    return number

def print_number(number):
    print(number)

number1 = get_number()
print_number(number1)

number2 = get_number()
print("my number is: {}\n".format(number2))
```

This gives your better separation between your logic and your ui.

Answer (score 5):

You can add in a function parameter that allows you to print out within the function or not:

```
def GetNumber(print_num=False):
    number = 45

    if print_num:
        print(number)

    return number

GetNumber(True)

num = GetNumber()

print("my num is: {}\n".format(num));
```

`GetNumber(True)` will print out the number from within the function, whereas `GetNumber()` will simply return the number without printing it. Note that in my example above, it returns the number regardless of how `print_num` is set. You can use it, or simply ignore it.

We set `print_num=False`. That means that if the parameter isn't sent in, we set a default value of `False` to it.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you would want to have some branch control to specify what parts of the function you would want to execute so you don't write dead code. But for the purpose of purely answering your question, the return value will break the function's execution. Example below:

```
def GetNumber():
    Number = 45
    return Number
    print("Getting Number")
    print("Found Number = " + str(Number))
```

This would only return 45. However, this is not the best way to write this method, since those print statements never get executed. I would suggest writing a new method, deleting code you don't need, or introducing some branch conditions (`if` `else`). Sorry for my first obscure answer.

Comment: This seems like a bad way of handling things. Why introduce dead code? It seems that OP needs a more basic explanation of how functions work.

Comment: Ugh ... I've been staring at Python all day, literally, and my brain is fried.I was under the impression that the return had to be at the end of the function, but I think this will work for me.

Comment: Unless there are conditions that make it so that the code would execute, commenting out the code would make sense. It all depends on the problem statement, but I'll edit to be more clear.

Comment: @level42 But adding a return at another point (non conditional) is just bad, because that means the rest of the function will never execute, and can thus just be deleted.

Comment: Hmm, I see you're point.

Comment: @level42 Then you need to refactor your code, and break out the common parts in one or more separate functions, calling just the part(s) you need at the different places.

Comment: So, I would have a function called `GetNumber`, and another called `GettingNumber` (for example) that does the print stuff with that number, and a third function called `UseNumber`

Comment: @level42 That might be one way to handle it. It of course depends on the length of your functions et cetera.

Comment: Would there be a better way to handle this? I have functions that generate results, and I would like them to be accessible in a number of other functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147309/discussion-between-level42-and-johanl).